# Model naming conflict leads to InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that has references to two Razor Class Libraries.  In each RCL, there is a Model class with the same name (Call it **GeneralModel**).  When the application is ran the following error occurs:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Namespace1.Models.**GeneralModel**', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'Namespace2.Models.**GeneralModel**'.

If I rename one of the Models in one of the RCLs to be unique, the error does not occur and the App preforms as expected.

I produced a bare bones App along with two bare bones RCLs to make sure it wasn't something in our real Solution.  The error re-occurred.

Here's the code:
RCL 1 Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TestRCL1.Models;

namespace TestRCL1.Controllers
{
    public class TestRCL1Controller : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                GeneralModel generalModel = new GeneralModel();
                generalModel.fooBar = "fooBar from RCL1";

                return PartialView("_GeneralView", generalModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RCL 2 Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TestRCL2.Models;

namespace TestRCL2.Controllers
{
    public class TestRCL2Controller : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                GeneralModel generalModel = new GeneralModel();
                generalModel.fooBar = "fooBar from RCL2";

                return PartialView("_GeneralView", generalModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RCL 1 Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestRCL1.Models
{
    public class GeneralModel
    {
        public string fooBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RCL 2 Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestRCL2.Models
{
    public class GeneralModel
    {
        public string fooBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RCL 1 View:

```
@model TestRCL1.Models.GeneralModel

<div>@Model.fooBar</div>
```

RCL 2 View:

```
@model TestRCL2.Models.GeneralModel

<div>@Model.fooBar</div>
```

Main App's Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TestRCLApp.Models;

namespace TestRCLApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Main App's Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <button id="loadRCL1Content" type="button">Load RCL1 Content</button>
    <button id="loadRCL2Content" type="button">Load RCL2 Content</button>

</div>

<script>
    $('#loadRCL1Content').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/TestRCL1/Index',
            type: 'POST'
        })
        .fail(function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        })
        .done(function (responseData, status, responseObj) {
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(responseData);
        });
    });

    $('#loadRCL2Content').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/TestRCL2/Index',
            type: 'POST'
        })
        .fail(function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        })
        .done(function (responseData, status, responseObj) {
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(responseData);
        });
    });

</script>
```

[Test App's Solution Explorer Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVdD.png)

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Do I just need to keep all the Model's uniquely named through out my RCLs or is there a better solution?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your error says it all.

Just because they look the same, doesn't mean they are the same. The compiler is smarter than that and will treat 2 separate classes **as** 2 separate classes.

Use the same model. or use an *interface* if you need

Comment: The intent of the RCL's is to be separate contained projects (each RCL can have it's own test project, and be self-contained units).  Thus, in the end, the hope was that it was sort of like having two different DLL's that one would reference.  We are going to end up with 100+ RCL's.  I wouldn't want to have to worry about class name collisions.  Especially when each RCL has it's own namespace.  So, I guess we don't get why the compiler gets confused.  One should be: RCL1.GeneralModel, the other should be RCL2.GeneralModel.

Comment: This is just example code to site the problem clearly.  Our real solution has many RCLs. When it's complete, it will have 50 or more of them being worked on by different developers.  Currently we have two RCLs in conflict because they both have a Model named "GeneralModel" with different implementations (so they can't share an interface.)  They are two totally different animals, they just happen to have the same name.

Comment: @JohnNorville if they just so happen to have the same name, you have to be explicit about the one you are targeting and either have the right using statement, or use its fully qualified name, `TestRCL2.Models.GeneralModel`

Comment: But, we are.  If you look at the RCL controllers, it's specific to the correct namespace (look at the Using clause we are using).

Comment: @JustLooking `TestRCL2.Controllers` uses `using TestRCL1.Models;` is this by design?

Comment: @TheGeneral I believe everything is fully qualified.  Both in the controllers, models and views.

Comment: @TheGeneral That was a typo, my bad.  John will fix that now.  But our test project, I assure you, is using the correct namespaces.  This is what has us scratching our head.  Did Microsoft really add these Models to that Dictionary without namespacing them!?

Comment: @TheGeneral That was a typo in my post here.  The actual code here is correct that causes the error.  I'll fix the post.

Comment: @JohnNorville, ahh ok, i am not in a situation where i can test this for myself, maybe someone else can though. good luck

Comment: @TheGeneral definitely appreciate the time you gave us.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the feedback though.  :)